# How to activate first li with active in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

Tried to active first li on starting but I do not know how to do it.From my code we can active after clicked the li but initially I want to active first li.How do it?

app.component.html:

```
 <ul id="grouplist" class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item}" (click)="listClick($event, item)" *ngFor="let item of groups">
        {{ item.name }}
     </li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts:

```
public selectedItem;
listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bviwht) in onInit set to first one.

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.selectedItem=this.groups[0];
  }
```

Comment: You're welcome :) if you get data from api assign this after you assigned api data to groups. set its first element to selected element.